# can the IP address assigned to a private endpoint in Azure change

Tags: azure, azure-private-link

Quoting from [Private Endpoint IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/manage-private-endpoint?tabs=manage-private-link-powershell#static-ip-address)

> By default, when a private endpoint is created the IP address for the
> endpoint is automatically assigned. The IP is assigned from the IP
> range of the virtual network configured for the private endpoint. A
> situation may arise when a static IP address for the private endpoint
> is required. The static IP address must be assigned when the private
> endpoint is created.

Are there any scenarios that could cause the IP addressed for the private endpoint to change ?

Comment: Private Endpoints are bound to the lifecycle of the resource to which they belong, so I think when you destroy and re-deploy the resource (and thus the private endpoint), chances are that you can get a new IP address assigned. This could be a realistic scenario with infrastructure-as-code scenarios, i.E. when using Terraform, ARM or bicep templates.

Comment: +1 good point. This could be indeed one scenario. Why I’m asking in first place, I’ve seen already few times, where people had used the private IP assigned to a private endpoint enabled Azure MySQL DB, rather than the FQDN (not mentioning whether hardcoding this in first place is the best way to do it but wouldn’t be able to verify each single configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Microsfot Azure Private Endpoint supports Static IP Address. so you will have the same IP even if you redeploy private endpoint